# ckan 2.9.0 iroute before_map not invoking custom controller

Tags: ckan

I recently updated ckan to 2.9.0. After the update, my custom controller for dataset.search will not be invoked from the plugin anymore. I can see that the templates of the plugins are still working, however, the customer controller is not invoked.

```
def before_map(self, map):

    # Hook in our custom user controller at the points of creation
    map.connect('dataset',controller='ckanext.facet.controller:CustomPakcageController',
                action='search')
```

It was working fine before the update. Any clue what changed or I did wrong in the file? Thanks!

Comment: i guess you mean 2.9.0, which is still alpha and could contain some bugs. In this version package controller is migrated to Flask blueprint, `views/dataset.py`. There could be some errors  when using custom controllers and old routes. If you can send the stack trace, will be really helpful

Comment: hi @tino097, many thanks for the info. Do you mean error stack trace? There is no error, CKAN just ignored the hook defined in `before_map` and uses the default controller. Please let me know, how I can provide more info on the question. Thanks!

Comment: @VicDing if possible, I'd suggest migrating from a pylons controller setup using `IRoutes` and try using the newer flask setup with `IBlueprint`. Here are some examples of the Flask setup https://github.com/ckan/ckan/blob/master/ckanext/example_flask_iblueprint/plugin.py. As @tino097 mentioned there may be some issues when using older routes. Testing if IBlueprint works would help determine if there's an error in the 2.9.0 **alpha** while it's still in development.