# How to customize ckan header site navigation tabs

Tags: jinja2, pylons, ckan

I would like to add extra header site navigation tabs to the default ones.

I have tried working with the solution given [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17777191/how-to-add-a-menu-item-to-ckans-naivigation-menu/) but it is not working for me. I am getting `Exception: menu item`api`cannot be found` error

This is my plugin.py code

```py
import ckan.plugins as plugins
import ckan.plugins.toolkit as toolkit

class ApiPlugin(plugins.SingletonPlugin, toolkit.DefaultDatasetForm):
    plugins.implements(plugins.IRoutes, inherit=True)
    def before_map(self, m):
        m.connect('api', #name of path route
            '/api', #url to map path to
            controller='ckanext.kimetrica_theme.controller:ApiController', #controller
            action='api') #controller action (method)
        return m
```

This is my header.html code

```py
{% ckan_extends %}

{% block header_site_navigation_tabs %}
  {{ h.build_nav_main(
    ('search', _('Datasets')),
    ('organizations_index', _('Organizations')),
    ('group_index', _('Groups')),
    ('about', _('About')),
    ('api', _('api'))
  ) }}
{% endblock %}
```

And this is my controller.py code

```py
import ckan.plugins as p
from ckan.lib.base import BaseController

class ApiController(BaseController):
    def api(self):
        return p.toolkit.render('api.html')
```

I expect to have the api menu work like the rest of the menu do. I also have my template(`api.html`) in place

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this question by using [ckanext-pages extension](https://github.com/ckan/ckanext-pages) This extension allows you to add simple static pages and blogs and edit their contents.

Answer (score 0):

Based on what you posted it looks like you haven't setup `plugins.implements(plugins.IConfigurer, inherit=True)` to register your new template. Try referencing this extension as an example. https://github.com/ckan/ckan/blob/2.8/ckanext/stats/plugin.py for setting up a new page.

You're on the right track for the menu.

Also what version of CKAN are you using? You may want to pswitch this to a flask blueprint. Like this https://github.com/ckan/ckan/blob/2.8/ckanext/example_flask_iblueprint/plugin.py

If you are using 2.9 (in alphha) check this issue out and the comments [ckan 2.9.0 iroute before_map not invoking custom controller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54987552/ckan-2-9-0-iroute-before-map-not-invoking-custom-controller)

Comment: I had `plugins.implements(plugins.IConfigurer, inherit=True)` setup but I did not share the entire code. I only shared the code related to this problem. I am using CKAN version 2.8. I decided to use `ckanext-pages` extension to achieve this but I will try out your suggestion as well. Regards

Comment: I solved this question by using `ckanext-pages extension` This extension allows you to add simple static pages and blogs and edit their contents.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by creating a new HTML file for the header, e.g. `header_foo.html`. Additionally, you have to change the `page.html`:

```
…
  {%- block header %}
    {% include "header_foo.html" %}
  {% endblock -%}
…
```

In the same way, you can hide the navigation tabs.